# Recycling frozen food packages

Tags: recycling

I know that frozen food boxes are not supposed to be recycled because the packages have a plastic coating that interferes with recycling.  However, lately I have been seeing frozen food boxes that are explicitly marked "please recycle" (e.g., Hilary's Eat Well).  Is this an indication that these packages do not have the non-recyclable coating, and can be safely recycled?  Or is this just misleading labeling?

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living SE. I've seen "Please recycle" claims on packaging I know my local recycler doesn't accept (e.g. compostable plastics). If the packaging doesn't say what it's made of then the only way to be sure is to ask the manufacturer. You may also want to check with your local recycler in which waste stream that should go.